# Should HtmlEncode be used when updating twitter status with Tweetsharp?

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

I am using tweetsharp to send tweets.

```
var response = _twitter.AuthenticateWith(item.TwitterToken, item.TwitterSecret)
    .Statuses().Update(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Tweet)).AsXml().Request().Response;
```

As you may have noticed, above I am HtmlEncoding the message this can cause the message to go over 140 chars? Is encoding the message this way necessary? Does tweetsharp or twitter recommend sending messages without encoding first?

Comment: You could always use .NET Reflector and see if it's being done already.

Comment: No need for Reflector.  It's open source: http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: I did look through the src a bit but couldn't find an encode reference

Comment: It is when the link is dead :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TweetSharp will handle all of the encoding for you.  Just pass it the string you want to post.

Comment: When passing the message without encoding '&' will break any messages sent through the service.

Comment: We made some encoding fixes last night.  Grab the latest code.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Things-Every-Developer-Should-Know#7Encodingaffectsstatuscharactercount):

> The Twitter API supports UTF-8
>   encoding. Please note that angle
>   brackets ("<" and ">") are
>   entity-encoded to prevent Cross-Site
>   Scripting attacks for web-embedded
>   consumers of JSON API output. The
>   resulting encoded entities do count
>   towards the 140 character limit. When
>   requesting XML, the response is UTF-8
>   encoded. Symbols and characters
>   outside of the standard ASCII range
>   may be translated to [HTML entities](http://www.webstandards.org/learn/reference/charts/entities/).

This says to me that you should indeed make sure that your output is encoded (not necessarily HTML encoded) to UTF-8. Have you tried to UTF-8 encode and then submit, then look at the output of "special" characters?

Comment: This says to me that the text must be UTF-8 character encoded, *and* that HTML entities must be escaped. ("entity-encoded")